# Não é possível localizar Controle ID no ControlParameter - Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

Olá,
estou com uma dúvida em obter o id de um autor de livros e adiciona-lo a criação de um livro, e o livro a ser publicado deverá ter um ID do Livro incrementando automático, um nome do livro e o  ID do autor.

A minha dúvida é obter o ID do autor obtidos através do Request.QueryString e adicioná-lo à tabela de livros e o erro que não foi possível encontrar control 'AutorID' em 'AutorID' ControlParameter.

função `Page_Load` para obter o `nome` e `id` do `autor` para mostrar na `div` **titulo**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  //obter o id do autor
  int autorId = Convert.toInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
  //obter o nome do autor
  string autorNome = Request["nome"];

  if (!IsPostBack) {
    if (autorNome != null) {
        AutorNomeLabel.Text = autorNome;
        AutorIDLabel.Text = Convert.toString(autorId);
    }
  }
}
```

nesta `div` com **titulo** como `id` que mostra o **nome** e **id** do `autor`

```
<div id="titulo">
  <h1>
  <asp:Label ID="AutorNomeLabel" runat="server" />
  <asp:Label ID="AutorIDLabel runat="server" />
 </h1>
</div>
```

a configuração do `SqlDataSource`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="LivrariaSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Livraria %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT [AutorID] FROM [Autor] WHERE [AutorNome] = @AuthorNomeLabel" 
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Livros] ([NomeLivro],[AutorID]) VALUES (@NomeLivro,@AutorID)">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="AutorID" ControlID="AuthorNomeLabel" Type="Int32" />
  </SelectParameters>
  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="NomeLivro" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="AutorID" Type="Int32" />
  </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Template para inserir o **nome** e **autor** do `Livro`

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
  Book Name:
  <asp:TextBox ID="NomeLivro" runat="server" CssClass="textBox" 
       Text='<%# Bind("NomeLivro")%>' />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="AutorID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("AutorID") %>' />
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Acho interessante adicionar a tag `webforms`

Comment: @jefersonb, obrigado, já adicionei...